# Call function on scroll when window is shown

Tags: javascript, function, scroll

I have a dive with the Id of "performance", In that div, I have an h1 with the class "counter". In the javascript code, there's a function that makes this h1 value count up to 150. the problem is that the countup starts when the page has loaded but I don't want that. I want it to start counting Up when the user has scrolled down and the div is visible on the window

**Here's the Html code:**

```
<h1 class="number" data-count="150">0</h1>
```

**And Here's the Javascript code:**

```
$(window).one('scroll', function() {
    $('.couter').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

        $({
            countNum: $this.text()
        }).animate({
                countNum: countTo
            },

            {

                duration: 5000,
                easing: 'linear',
                step: function() {
                    $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $this.text(this.countNum);
                    //alert('finished');
                }

            });

    });
    $(window).off('scroll');
});
```